# Values expression not evaluating dynamically

Tags: list-manipulation, dynamic, associations

I am having a problem with applying `Values` to a list of rules within a dynamic module.

The list of rules is in the following format `{a -> 1, b -> 2, ...}` where all the keys are the variable names of an association (e.g., `a = <|x1 -> 3,x2 -> 2|>`) and the values are just integers. I used

```
associationNames = HoldForm[#] & /@ Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated@{a, b, c}
```

to get a list of the associations names (if I hadn't, the list of rules would evaluate and become

> {<|x1 -> 3, x2 -> 2|> -> 1, ... }.

Inside my dynamic module the list of rules is generated by

```
MapThread[Rule,{associationNames, amounts}
```

where `amounts` come from input fields. When I try to call `Values` on the list of rules, it does not evaluate. It just outputs

> `Values[{a -> 1, b -> 2}]`.

EDIT (Code Added)

```
a = <|x -> 1, y -> 2|>;
b = <|x -> 3, y -> 4|>;
variableList = HoldForm[#] & /@ Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated@{a, b};
DynamicModule[
 {dropDown = variableList, dropDownValue,
  variableName = {},
  amounts = {},
  listOfRules
  },     
 Column[{
   Row[{
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[dropDownValue], dropDown],
     Button["+",
      {
       variableName = variableName~Append~dropDownValue,
       amounts = amounts~Append~0
       }
      , Alignment -> Center, Appearance -> "Palette"]
     }],
   Dynamic[
    Column[{
        Panel[
         Row[{#,
           Button["x",
            {amounts = 
              amounts~Delete~Flatten[Position[variableName, #]],                 
             variableName = 
              variableName~Delete~Flatten[Position[variableName, #]]}
            ],               
           InputField[
            Dynamic[amounts[[Flatten@Position[variableName, #]]]]]
           }]
         ]
        }] & /@ variableName
    ],
   {"Amount: ", Dynamic[amounts]},
   {"Name: ", Dynamic[# & /@ variableName]},
   listOfRules = Dynamic@MapThread[Rule, {variableName, amounts}];
   Values[listOfRules]
   }]
 ]
```

After using the top controls to input values for `a` and `b`

> ```
> {Amount: ,{0,0}}
> {Name: ,{a,b}}
> Values[{a -> 0, b -> 0}]
> ```

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in a form that readers can copy and execute.

Comment: I'm working on simplifying the code to post (as it is very long). I just posted the question first to see if this was a simple problem occurring with `HoldForm[]` and `Unevaluted[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is quite what you want, but it fixes your immediate problem. It might give you a start on moving forward.

Basically your problem is two-fold: not applying `Dynamic` in the right places (often a tricky business), and not putting everything need into 1st `Column` expression.

```
a = <|x -> 1, y -> 2|>;
b = <|x -> 3, y -> 4|>;
variableList = HoldForm[#] & /@ Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated @ {a, b};
DynamicModule[
  {dropDown = variableList, dropDownValue, variableName = {}, 
   amounts = {}, listOfRules}, 
  Dynamic @ 
   Column[
    {Row[
       {PopupMenu[Dynamic[dropDownValue], dropDown], 
        Button["+", 
          {variableName = variableName ~ Append ~ dropDownValue, 
           amounts = amounts ~ Append ~ 0}, 
          Alignment -> Center, 
          Appearance -> "Palette"]}], 
     Column[
       (Panel[
          Row[
            {#, 
             Button["x", 
               {amounts = amounts ~ Delete ~ Flatten[Position[variableName, #]], 
                variableName = variableName ~ Delete ~ 
                  Flatten[Position[variableName, #]]}], 
             InputField[
               Dynamic[amounts[[Flatten @ Position[variableName, #]]]]]}]] & 
         /@ variableName)],
     {"Amount: ", amounts},
     {"Name: ", amounts# & /@ variableName}, 
     listOfRules = MapThread[Rule, {variableName, amounts}]; Values[listOfRules]}]]
```

[image: dynamic]

Comment: That worked out splendidly. Why does applying `Dynamic[]` to `Values[]` (i.e. `Dynamic[Values[x]]`) not evaluate, but applying `Dynamic[]` to the whole Column does (since `listofRules` still dynamically updates)?

Comment: @IshouldchangemyUsername. Think of `Dynamic` as a tag that means "look inside this form for variables have changed and update it when true". The front-end didn't see any variables it was tracking inside `Values[listOfRules]`; i.e., `listOfRules` isn't being tracked. Note: I edited the answer to remove two other `Dynamic` wrappers -- those being wrapped around the output of "Amount" and "Name". No longer needed because the `Dynamic` I placed around `Column` takes care of them too.